# Unable to explain flow of steps in this basic modular expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Consider the expresion $(13 + 11)· 18 (\mod 7)$:

> $(13+11)· 18 ≡ (6+4)· 4 (\mod 7)$  Note the transition from $(13+11)·
> > 18$$\implies$ $(6+4)· 4$
>
> $≡ 10 · 4 (\mod 7)$
>
> $≡ 3 · 4 (\mod 7)$ Note the transition from $10 · 4$$\implies$ $3 · 4$
>
> $≡ 12 (\mod 7)$
>
> $≡ 5 (\mod 7)$
>
> $≡ 5$

---

These 2 transitions involve subtracting 7, but in each case they were either the factor( the $10$ going to $7$ in the 2nd transition) or a component of a factor( the $13$ and $11$ going to $6$ and $4$ in first transition).

I would have understood if they subtracted 7 from the product itself( like the $12$ going to $7$ in the final step) because I can intutively understand that the equivalence that both sides have the same remainder when divided by 7 still holds.

I didn't get how this was possible( there wasn't any law/theorem stating you could do that). Few pages down , I saw this corollary:

> $ab ≡ [(a \mod n)(b \mod n)](\mod n)$

Is the transitions some result of the corollary or is there some knowledge I'm lacking entirely to explain those transitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corollary is indeed the key! In case we have:
$$
a\pmod n=x\\
b\pmod n=y
$$
we can write
$$
a=pn+x\\
b=qn+y
$$
and therefore
$$
a\cdot b=pq\cdot n+(py+qx)n+x\cdot y
$$
showing that
$$
a\cdot b\equiv x\cdot y\pmod n
$$
so this establishes the result, which could also be formulated as

> When you do modular arithmetics on products, you can reduce each factor first.

---

To clarify why partial reductions will also work, let us prove a slightly different result that
$$
a\cdot b\equiv(a+kn)\cdot b\pmod n
$$
This can be seen from
$$
(a+kn)\cdot b=a\cdot b+bk\cdot n
$$
So when $a$ is changed by $kn$ the product is changed by $bk\cdot n$

> Changing one factor of a product by a multiple of $n$ changes the product by a multiple of $n$

Comment: Did you mean $\equiv$ sign in the first section? I get that $a\cdot b\equiv x\cdot y\pmod n$ but how does that make this expression acceptable(trying to illustrate the transition I'm talking about): $a\cdot b\equiv (x-n)\cdot y\pmod n$?

Comment: @Leon: Did you mean $a\cdot b\equiv(a-n)\cdot b\pmod n$? This follows from the fact that you stay within modulo classes, namely $$a\equiv a-n\equiv a\pm tn\equiv x\pmod n$$ so you can add or subtract any multiples of $n$ without leaving the equivalence class.

Comment: @Leon: To put it slightly differently, if you can use $a$ or $x$ interchangeably, you can use any other $a'\equiv x$ as well.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, I get that adding/subtracting multiples of $n$ from the product won't change its equivalence class, just can't wrap my head around why doing that to a factor also won't change its equivalence class? Is proving something like $$
x.y=hn+r\\
\implies(x + kn).y=qn+r
$$ sufficient to explain why you can do those transitions?

Comment: @Leon: See my last update with a clarification addressing the last point you are asking about. Does that get you closer to seeing the *grand picture*?

Comment: @Leon: Ah, your last comment is exactly on point! That is the/one relevant result to prove to make ends meet.

Comment: Just 1 last clarification! For the last equation I get this $(a+kn)\cdot b=a\cdot b-q\cdot n$. How did you get the $-q$ to change to $bk$ ?

Comment: @Leon: You distribute the product: $(a+kn)\cdot b=a\cdot b+kn\cdot b$ and rearrange the last term. For instance $(7 - 2\cdot 3)\cdot 5=7\cdot 5 - 2\cdot5\cdot3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us define a rule and prove its truth.

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ then:

$a = bn+c \implies a \bmod n = c \bmod n$

Proof:

$a \bmod n = (bn+c) \bmod n = (0 + c) \bmod n = c \bmod n$

Now because this is true, we can say:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
18(13+11) \bmod 7 & ≡ 18(7+6+7+4) \bmod 7 \\ & ≡ 18(6+4) \bmod 7 \\ & ≡ (14(6+4)+4(6+4)) \bmod 7 \\ & ≡ 4(6+4) \bmod 7 \\& ≡ 40 \bmod 7 \\& ≡ (7*5+5) \bmod 7 \\& ≡ 5 \bmod 7
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Let me know if there is anything I can clarify :)

Comment: 1) How does the $bn$ suddenly become 0? 2)How does proving this equivalence allows to explain the transitions from the factor/component of factor? Sorry, I'm bit slow on the uptake

Comment: That's fine. Because $bn$ is a multiple of $n$, $bn \bmod n$ is $0$ (this is the same as saying $bn$ divided by $n$ is an integer which is true because $b$ is an integer). In your problem, $n = 7$. Now, the reason this is relevant is because with every simplification we are taking out a multiple of $7$. Again please let me know if there is more to clarify :)

Comment: Ah, so you meant $(bn+c)\mod n$? So the key idea is to split them into multiples of $n$, ie,$7$ (if I'm not wrong, something like a distributive law) and then use that proof to make them $0$? Can I just confirm something: is the idiomatic way of doing the calculations, the one in the question or the one in your answer?

Comment: yes that is what i meant, i clarified my post. now both are technically idiomatically correct because there are multiple ways to split a number into a multiple of 7 and another number. for example, $4(10) = 4(7)+4(3)$ but also $4(10) = 5(7) + 5$. hope that makes sense!

Comment: You don't realise how helpful this is, thanks!( I know comments are not meant for this but still)

Comment: I hope his does not come off the wrong way, but you are essentially re-proving the corollary each step of the way in the reduction rather than to prove it first and utilize it to simplify the steps. That being said, it is always nice to see numerical examples of how principles work to aid the understanding. Sometimes I do that a lot before proving the results.

Comment: this is true but I felt that the use of the corollary was the confusion so it was best to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: @justaguy: That makes sense! Unpacking the numerical process can be quite illuminating as well, just like I stated at the end.